# Ionic 4: How to import mixins globally, not having to import them in specific files?

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic4, scss-mixins

I am upgrading to Ionic 4. How can I import mixins globally and having to import the file in every sass that uses a mixin? I've tried editing `angular.json`, `global.scss` and `variables.scss` but no luck.

It should be adding the import to global with the line `@import "./mixins";`. I've tried adding it as the first line and the last line.

Comment: Find any solutions here?

Comment: No not yet.....

Comment: I have the same issue. I think the sass compatibility is not good enough yet on the beta version of Ionic 4.... I am copypasting as a workaround (ass tupid as it seems).

Comment: Any solution for this nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

In ionic 4 i manually added file "ionic.mixin.scss" under folder theme and I have imported it into the .scss file to consume it. It's works fine!

Comment: I want to import it once and have it available everywhere not having to import it every time I need a mixin.

Comment: but you need to import it file by file. You cannot import it on a global one as we used to do with Ionic 3